# Adobe Premiere - Double image between cuts?

Tags: video, adobe-premiere, ghost

I'm importing a video into Premiere that's 1080p, MP4, HEVC codec, 23.976 FPS, Variable framerate.

I am getting problems on most cuts, the last frame of the 1st clip is half there, along with the first frame of the 2nd clip, like so:

[image]

As well as this (and this could be related too) whenever there's any motion at all, there's a ghosting problem like this:

[image]

I have tried setting "Sequence Settings" to match the FPS exactly, doesn't solve it.

I have tried setting "Sequence Settings" to 24 FPS, doesn't solve it.

I have "No Fields (Progressive Scan)" also set in Sequence Settings, no luck.

I tried making a proxy version of the video for smoother editing, the same problem happens.

I have tried re-encoding the video with FFMPEG so it has a constant framerate, doesn't solve it.

I have tried to search for anyone else posting anywhere else about this and can't find anything.

Is there some obvious thing that can fix it, I'm not doing?

Here's the Sequence Settings, but they are only what I have always used in the past on 1080p, 23.976 FPS videos, with H264 and HEVC and I have never seen this ghosting problem happening between clips, with any other videos.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by clicking "Video" then "Match Source" while exporting. It had 29.97 FPS set there on the problematic exports. EDIT: Although in the timeline this still occurs. If I notice it on the proxy version and untick proxy, it's not on the original. I have some sort of seeking problem for some reason. I'm not seeing the overlapping image anymore between clips on the exported video so it's sort of solved.